# Is 何と read as なにと or なんと in 何と言いましたか?

Tags: readings, contractions

> 彼は**何と**言いましたか.

What is the reading of 何と in 何と言いましたか. Is it (なに or なん) + と?

Comment: For your first question, see [Surprise and animosity: The use of the copula *da* in quotative sentences in Japanese (Satoko Suzuki, 1998)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y8jlWyEe1E0C&pg=PA239&ots=-Hdf_AFwoW)

Comment: なんて is also acceptable, and I use なんて.

Comment: Dekiru, please ask one question per question post.  I'm splitting this post up; I've edited out the first question (about the role of だ in 何だと), because the answers/comments you've received so far focus on the second question (the reading of 何と).  Could you please repost the first question about the role of だ in 何だと separately?  It's a great question and I hope it gets an answer when it's reposted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「彼{かれ}は**何と**言{い}いましたか。」 ("What did he say?")

「何と」 should be read 「な**ん**と」 in that context.

Reading it 「な**に**と」 will ***not*** make it sound more formal or anything in this case.  It will only make it sound incorrect and bizarre as far as Standard Japanese is concerned.

When is 「何と」 read 「な**に**と」, then?

It can be read 「なにと」 when saying "with what?" emphatically.  For instance, if I said:

> 「チーズと一緒{いっしょ}に食{た}べるとおいしいよ。」 ("It's yummy if you eat it  with cheese.")

and you did not catch the 「チーズ」 part for some reason.  In that case, you might reply:

> 「**なにと**一緒に食べるとおいしいって（言った）？」 (It's yummy if you eat it ***with what***?)

Even in this example, you can still use 「なんと」.

Answer (score 0):

I think both なんと and なにと are acceptable, but なんと is more common way of pronouncing it, because なにと just doesn't slide off your tongue. This kind of sound morphing is common in Japanese.